# react native and native base picker component

Tags: javascript, react-native, native-base

I want to create picker component for android and as well as for ios, but facing problem in styling.

What I want to accomplish is to style picker text which is being displayed by default(it can be placeholder or the selected item from picker list).

I have tried the below code but it is not working.

```js
<View style={{ backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF", borderRadius: 3, height: 39, marginTop:5, }}>
  <Picker style={{ width: screenWidth, opacity:0.4, }}

    textStyle={{ color: "blue" }}
    itemStyle={{
    backgroundColor: "green",
    marginLeft: 0,
    paddingLeft: 10
    }}
    itemTextStyle={{ color: '#788ad2' }}
  >
  
    <Picker.Item label="Java" value="java" />
    <Picker.Item label="JavaScript" value="js" />
  </Picker>
</View>
```

Any help will be a big plus.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace `itemStyle` code with the snippet below.

```
itemStyle={{
          color: "red",
          fontFamily: "Georgia",
          fontSize: 50,
          backgroundColor: "green",
          textAlign: 'left',
        }}
```

You can apparently use [Text Style Props](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text-style-props) to add styling to the text of `Picker`, `PickerIOS` in `React Native`.

Answer (score 0):

To style the selected item, you just need to put your preference styles into `itemStyle`. 
'textStyle' and 'itemTextStyle' are illegal props, you could check the provided props on this [docs](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-website/blob/master/docs/picker.md)

Furthermore, you could use any of [this text styles](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-website/blob/master/docs/text-style-props.md) for `itemStyle` as described on [this section](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-website/blob/master/docs/picker.md#itemstyle)

**edit:**
you could import `Dimension` from react-native package

> import { Dimensions } from 'react-native';

```js
    <View style={styles.container}>
    <Picker style={{ width: Dimensions.get('window').width, opacity:0.4}}
      itemStyle={{
        color: "blue",
        backgroundColor: "green",
        marginLeft: 0,
        paddingLeft: 10
      }}
    >

      <Picker.Item label="Java" value="java" />
      <Picker.Item label="JavaScript" value="js" />
    </Picker>
  </View>
```